# How can I set up Lisp with Sublime text 2 in Windows?

Tags: lisp, sublimetext2, common-lisp

How can I set up Common Lisp to work with sublime text 2. Is there a way to set it up so I can compile and run the code easily, I am new to both lisp and sublime text.

Answer (score 2):

For Sublime Text, I'd recommend [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) for the REPL. The default configuration for Common Lisp uses SBCL nowadays, I think (Previously it was CLISP). To download a binary of SBCL for Windows, just go to the [downloads page](http://sbcl.org/platform-table.html).

I've never installed SBCL on Windows, but the installation should be fairly simple.

To install Quicklisp, follow the [instructions](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/#installation) in the website.

Comment: Could you explain what to do with this. You've given me something to download but I don't know how I can use it to run lisp on ST

Comment: @sam once you have a Lisp on your system and have installed SublimeREPL, just see its menu, start it and choose SBCL from the list. https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html#sublime-text

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually compile anything with Sublime Text, because it is just text editor. But there are plugin for sublime text 2/3 that claimed to properly indents lisp code: [lispindent](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/lispindent).

So, you can write your CL program with it just by creating .lisp text-file. Then you can run it with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/platform-table.html) as easy as  `(load "C:/path-to-your-file.lisp")`.

And yes, to work with something more difficult than "Hello, world!" you will need Quicklisp as a package manager for Common Lisp.

Comment: That's actually not true. Sublime Text can be used to compile code via ⌘+B. For more details on how to set it up for to compile via SBCL, see http://marktrapp.com/blog/2014/01/20/lisp-with-os-x-sublime-text/

Comment: You can compile files with sublime text using the "Build System" feature.